# Why Doesn't Thermal Radiation Render Thermionic Conversion Unable To Approach Carnot Efficiency?

Tags: thermal-radiation, power, photoelectric-effect, carnot-cycle

[Thermionic Conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_converter) follows the classic Richardson-Dushmann Equation for thermionic current as a function of temperature squared:

$$J_{RD} = A_0 T^2 \exp\left(-\frac{\phi}{k_B T}\right)$$
where

- $J_{RD}$ is the emission current density.
- $T$ is the emission temperature.
- $A_0$ is a material specific correction factor
- $\phi$ is the material's environment-mediated [work function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function), and
- $k_B$ is is the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant)

But [thermal power loss is a function of the fourth power of temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation#Radiative_power) following the Stefan-Boltzmann law:
\begin{equation}
P=A\sigma T^4
\end{equation}
where

- $P$ is the power lost to thermal radiation
- $T$ is the emission temperature.
- $A$ is the area of thermal emission, and
- $\sigma$ is the [Stefan-Bolzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant)

Although I see a lot of talk about [space charge buildup being the limiting factor on thermionic conversion efficiency](https://avs.scitation.org/doi/10.1116/1.3125282), the power of 2 disadvantage from thermal radiation losses seems to make thermionic conversion a fundamentally impractical approach to approximating Carnot efficiency.

What am I missing?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

According to this article, ["Thermionic Energy Conversion in the Twenty-first Century: Advances and Opportunities for Space and Terrestrial Applications"](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmech.2017.00013/full), the thermal radiation actually is a design concern.

You mention two power laws, and yes it does imply that at high temperatures the efficiency must drop, but it also equally implies that at low enough temperatures, the effect of the thermal radiation must become negligible.

The power of the power law is not the only thing, and in evaluating whether a technology sinks or swims, it comes down to a practical question of what are the actual coefficients, etc., and what is the final tradeoff that gets made in engineering.

Comment: I modified my question to be more pertinent.  For instance, that paper states "...there is no physical/chemical reason that a thermionic converter cannot operate near the Carnot efficiency with high-power generation." Since ambient heat sink temperature can't be changed, one must raise the input temperature -- which is what motivates my focus on temperature scaling.

Comment: Well, as the article mentions, if you can lower $\sigma$ then you win. This is not so hard for infrared radiation and shiny metal surfaces.

Comment: As for approaching Carnot efficiency, I think there is an implicit qualifier "at appropriate temperatures". Every heat engine in existence has some practical concerns like this: even if they can reach Carnot at one temperature pair, it will likely not be true at all temperature pairs. Some can hold this over a wider range, others are only operating efficiently in a narrow range around a particular temperature pair.

Comment: In the case of a radioisotope thermal generator, the source can get as hot as you want. So, you might not even care about approaching Carnot efficiency, rather you care most about absolute efficiency.

Comment: I was unable to locate a "$\sigma$" in the article.  What is it?

Comment: The article states: "Thus, at least ideally, it is possible for a thermionic convertor to approach the Carnot efficiency. Further, given the high temperatures thermionic emission is compatible with, this efficiency can be relatively high. For example, a 'standard' convertor might operate with an 1,800 K emitter and 1,000 K collector, leading to Carnot efficiency of 44%."  However, I see no justification in the article for the claim that thermionic efficiency can achieve 44%.  What is a "'standard' convertor"?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to say "emissivity" which is not $\sigma$ but rather usually $\varepsilon$. Low emissivity means low radiation.

Anyway, this argument is tiring, you have not provided an actual equation for the upper limit to thermionic efficiency that you are so worried about. Let me know when you have derived it.